# Problema con menú al activar modal

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap, web, http

Cada vez que activo el modal, la barra de menús se sale de la pantalla junto con el modal y por ende la barra de menú me oculta el titulo del modal y el principio del contenido, vean:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

HTML de la barra de menu

```
<div id="navigation">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-custom" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="site-logo">
                            <a href="index.html" class="brand">
                                <img src="img/archivo-synergy-curva.png" style="height: 50px;">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>                                         

                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu">
                                <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menu">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="ejm2">
                                <li class="active"><a href="#intro">Inicio</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#about">Nuestra Empresa</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#service">Misión y Visión</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#works">Portafolio TIC</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#clientes">Nuestros Clientes</a></li>                                                                                
                                <li><a href="#partner">Nuestros Aliados</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#contact">Contactenos</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.Navbar-collapse -->                             
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                          <!-- /.container -->
        </nav>
    </div>
```

CSS principal de la barra de navegacion:

```
#navigation {
background: #fff;
z-index: 9999;
width:100%;
box-sizing:border-box;
border-bottom: 1px solid orangered;
```

}

Comment: Creo que el problema que tienes es que la modal al igual que el menu superior pueden tener el mismo z-index, o en su caso, la modal esta dentro de un div diferente a donde esta el menu principal. Puedes añadir el codigo html de tu modal con tu menú?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sin codigo es dificil ayudar pero intenta sobreponer un valor al modal superior a todo con un z index ejemplo

```
//suponiendo que este sea el div de el modal 
#modal{z-index:3000;}

suponiendo que este sea el div de la barra de navegacion le das un valor menor 
#navbar{z-index:2000;}
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda @andy gibbs

Comment: por nada para eso estamos @LeonardJusaOckonell si te sirvio el codigo recuerda marcar le respuesta como valida

Comment: Yo también tengo ese mismo problema, pero con el  z-index no lo he resuelto.